# Trying to open folder location but keep getting errors

Tags: vb.net, windows-explorer

I am using Process.Start() and other options to open a folder location through Windows Explorer. It works fine on my local machine, but not through the server. All I need to do is open a folder location on a shared drive that every user has access to, I feel this should not be that hard. The same shared drive and parent folder is used to hold the application pages for the website as well as any templates and images that are used in the code.

I am using Telerik's RadAsyncUpload control to upload a file to the specific folder and then an image button to view all of the attached items within the folder based on a specific ID #. Here is the code for the button click event where it displays everything I have tried without success:

```
'DECLARE VARIABLES
Dim cadNum As String = hfCadNum.Value.ToString()
Dim path As String = My.Settings.CadLogFolder + "\" + cadNum.ToString()

If Directory.Exists(path) Then
    'Process.Start(path)
    'Process.Start("explorer.exe", path)
    'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR")
        '+ "\explorer.exe", path)
    Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(path)
    pi.UseShellExecute = True
    pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    pi.Verb = "OPEN"

    Dim proc As New Process()
    proc.StartInfo = pi
    proc.Start()
Else
    lblErrFolder.Text = "There are no attached files."
End If
```

I don't get any error message when running this on the server, except for the first and last attempts, and no explorer window pops up. These are all of the suggestions that I have come across and none of them are working.

I don't believe this is a permission issue because the webpage is located in the same parent folder and all users have access to this shared drive.

Comment: I bet it is a permissions issue. Meaning when it is launched on the server trying to open the folder on the shared drive, it is getting blocked.

Comment: @codeMonger123 If it is a permission issue, how would I go about resolving it?

Comment: O - well I dont know if this is the best way to do it but I created my own custom mapped drive code to map to the servers drive and use credentials to ensure there are no permissions issues. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793623/map-network-drive-programatically